# After upgrading to 1.2.162.1: vkQueueWaitIdle == VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST

Tags: c++, vulkan

I recently upgraded my ray tracing renderer from Vulkan SDK version 1.2.148.0 to 1.2.162.1.
This was necessary because the ray tracing extension went out of beta and thus now works with non-beta
graphics drivers (am on version 461.40 for my RTX 2070 SUPER). It required me to make quite a few changes to the ray tracing side of my renderer which
I managed thanks to the nvidia tutorial.

Unfortunately, code that used to work started to cause errors now.
In many situations, submitting a single time command causes vkQueueWaitIdle to fail with VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST which results in a validation error, saying I'm trying to free the command buffer while it's still in use. This happens for a variety of uses: transitioning an image layout(undef to general it seems), building acceleration structures, copying buffers but not every time (e.g. from a staging to a device buffer, after which freeing the staging buffer also throws an error, since it's still in use, the copy not having finished)... But for other uses, it works fine. I can't currently identify a common denominator...

Finally, the program crashes because presenting the first frame fails, because its layout is undefined - I assume this is caused by one or more of the previously mentioned errors.

Did something change about this since last I used it? This is the offending code (endSingleTimeCommands):

```cpp
    vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo{};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
    submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffer;

    vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
    switch (vkQueueWaitIdle(graphicsQueue)) {
        //debug output removed for brevity
    };

    vkFreeCommandBuffers(device, commandPool, 1, &commandBuffer);
```

One of the places where it fails is this:

```cpp
    //[fill the structs with info...]

    //function pointer grabbed via vkGetDeviceProcAddr
    vk::vkCmdBuildAccelerationStructuresKHR(cmd, 1, &buildInfo, &buildOffset);

    //[call to the above code here]
```

But also code unrelated to extensions fails (sometimes!) such as this one:

```cpp
    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = beginSingleTimeCommands();

    VkBufferCopy copyRegion{};
    copyRegion.srcOffset = 0; // Optional
    copyRegion.dstOffset = 0; // Optional
    copyRegion.size = size;
    vkCmdCopyBuffer(commandBuffer, srcBuffer, dstBuffer, 1, &copyRegion);

    endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer);
```

Perhaps beginSingleTimeCommands is also relevant:

```cpp
    VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo allocInfo{};
    allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    allocInfo.level = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
    allocInfo.commandPool = commandPool;
    allocInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;

    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer;
    if (vkAllocateCommandBuffers(device, &allocInfo, &commandBuffer) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "beginSingleTimeCommands: could not allocate command buffer!\n";
    }

    VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo{};
    beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
    beginInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT;

    if (vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "beginSingleTimeCommands: could not begin command buffer!\n";
    }

    return commandBuffer;
```

Some additional info I think I gathered:
I used the nvidia pipeline checkpoint system to add a checkpoint before and after the call to vkCmdBuildAccelerationStructuresKHR and both checkpoints are at TOP_OF_PIPE. After the first call to this function, no more checkpoint output is generated, leading me to believe that the first call to the build somehow ruins everything. I will triplecheck my AS building I guess, I'll get back to you if I find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, the actual error can occur before the command buffer whose vkQueueWaitIdle returns the DEVICE_LOST error. I've had and continue to have a variety of errors in my acceleration structure building code. I can't easily debug it, because apparently the validation layers don't show if there's subtle mistakes in the structs fed to vkCmdBuildAccelerationStructures, instead it's a lot of trial and error.

One notable example which I'm certain would've been caught by the validation layers pre-upgrade is forgetting to set the `VkAccelerationStructureBuildGeometryInfoKHR::scratchData` field, the last mistake I had to fix to finally get everything to run.

The answer to my question is thus: Don't look at the commands that trigger the DEVICE_LOST, look at what you do with the queue *before* that command, there's a chance the error is there, instead. In fact, once the first DEVICE_LOST error occurred, (almost?) all further vkQueueWaitIdle failed with the same error (same with the vkQueueSubmit). In cases such as my copy buffer code being the first to fail, the error was always found in the queue usage *before* that one.

I can't post the exact solution to my problem as - like I've said - there's more than one cause and I've only fixed some of them so far, there's still some left. I think the details are not relevant to future people who come across my question but if there's anything I can add to help other people, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is so true! I was stuck with this issue for couple of days only to figure out that VkAccelerationStructureBuildGeometryInfoKHR flags was mismatching when I query the size using vkGetAccelerationStructureBuildSizesKHR() vs when I use it to actually build the BLAS! In my case, I was using VK_BUILD_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_PREFER_FAST_TRACE_BIT_KHR | VK_BUILD_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_ALLOW_UPDATE_BIT_KHR while querying the size and only FAST_TRACE while actually creating the AS, this was causing the same issue!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29922755)