# Vulkan Device Lost = Missing Synchronization, but I don't know how

Tags: vulkan

I try to figure out how to use the ray tracing. What I have is a rasterizer drawed Triangle (most the same as shown by Vulkan tutorials, but refactored into my own code and utility functions). The recreation of the swapchain due to window resizing/minimizing, etc. works correctly.

Then I have added the creation of a bottom acceleration structure. And since then I get some Device Lost errors, but not always... Here is a skeleton of my code:

```
mainLoop:
- acquireNextImage
- renderWorld
- render gui
- present

acquireNextImage:
- signaling a semaphore "Image Available"

render gui:
- wait for fence "Gui"
- begin command buffer (use graphics queue)
- begin render pass
- bind pipeline (graphics)
- set viewport
- set scissor
- draw (2 triangles in my GUI yet)
- end render pass
- end command buffer
- reset fence "Gui"
- submit command buffer (waiting for semaphore "Image Available", signaling semaphore "Rendering Done", checking fence "Gui")

present:
- queue present (waiting for semaphore "Rendering Done")

renderWorld:
(actually this does not render anything yet, it just creates a vertex buffer, an index buffer, and creates the bottom acceleration strucutre for it - and caches it for further frames, so this code runs only once at start!)
- == vertexbuffer ==
- create buffer (usage transfer dst)
- get buffer memory requirements
- allocate memory (device local)
- bind buffer memory
- create buffer (usage transfer src) (this is my staging buffer)
- get buffer memory requirements
- allocate memory (host visible, host coherent) (this is my staging memory)
- bind buffer memory
- wait for fence "Transfer"
- begin command buffer (use dedicated transfer queue)
- copy buffer
- end command buffer
- reset fence "Transfer"
- submit command buffer (checking fence "Transfer")
- wait queue idle
- free stating memory
- destroy staging buffer
- == indexbuffer ==
- create buffer (usage transfer dst)
- get buffer memory requirements
- allocate memory (device local)
- bind buffer memory
- create buffer (usage transfer src) (this is my staging buffer)
- get buffer memory requirements
- allocate memory (host visible, host coherent) (this is my staging memory)
- bind buffer memory
- wait for fence "Transfer"
- begin command buffer (use dedicated transfer queue)
- copy buffer
- end command buffer
- reset fence "Transfer"
- submit command buffer (checking fence "Transfer")
- wait queue idle
- free stating memory
- destroy staging buffer
- == bottom acceleration structure ==
- get acceleration structure build sizes info
- create buffer (acceleration structure storage, shader device address)
- create acceleration structure (bottom level)
- create buffer (acceleration structure storage, shader device address) (this is my scratch buffer)
- wait for fence "BuildAcc"
- begin command buffer (use dedicated compute queue)
- pipeline barrier (transfer write -> acceleration structure write), don't know if I need it here
- build acceleration structures
- pipeline barrier (acceleration structure write -> shader read), don't know if I need it here
- end command buffer
- reset fence "BuildAcc"
- submit command buffer (checking fence "BuildAcc")
- wait queue idle                                      <------- here device lost
- destroy scratch buffer
```

So, if I comment out "renderWorld", all works fine. If I let renderWorld be in, then I get a device lost (see the last "wait queue idle" line). But not every time I run the program.

If I put a breakpoint on the "wait queue idle" line, and after the program stops at this line, I can continue the program and all is fine. Also if I comment out the "build acceleration structures" command, all is working (except of course there is no acc structure, but there is no device lost).

So I don't know where the problem is. In my opinion, I need to synchronize something somehow, because with the break point I can run it and it works. So the code must be OK as I understand it.

There is also no validation error except missing shader bindings, but because I do not use them yet (I don't ray trace render yet), it should not be a problem.

After the device lost, the other semaphores are not reset and also my gui render path is not working anymore.

Can somebody tell me if I missed a synchronisation somewhere? And how I can add it? I don't have copied my whole code here, because it would be tons of code. But if  you need some piece of code, then ask for it, and I can paste it here.

Comment: OK, if I add a breakpoint right on the beginning of the render loop, and if the application stops there, then if I remove the breakpoint, all is working fine. I can recreate the swapchain etc. there are no errors.

But instead of putting a breakpoint if I put a sleep there (triggered only once), then it does not work. I get device loses in 50% cases at the beginning, and in 50% after I resize my window and trigger a swapchain recreation (and all other resources created until then). So, I still don't understand, what is going here :D

Comment: To narrow down the problem, you could comment-out parts of your code or add [`vkDeviceWaitIdle`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkDeviceWaitIdle.html) calls at multiple places until the problem no longer occurs. Then, start to remove the `vkDeviceWaitIdle` calls again until the problem re-emerges.

Comment: The problem is not that Vulkan is coddddy. Problem is that your example is **not** _minimal_; i.e. it contains cruft that is not relevant to expose the bug. To build acceleration structure you don't need swapchain or gui. you don't even need to render anything, and suddenly you are left with a neat 500 LOC that can easily be scanned over by someone used to Vulkan (or more likely you would find the bug in the process). And because you skipped that, it is an excuse to make your example not complete and not verifiable too.

Comment: Device lost can be literaly anything. E.g. this is a [duplicate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66198321/after-upgrading-to-1-2-162-1-vkqueuewaitidle-vk-error-device-lost), where it seems an invalid argument is the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, check my answer (problem still occurs, even with a brand new code *g*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem! This here was the right hint and seams to be the same problem as mine:

https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/fqu90h/submitting_command_buffer_to_compute_queue_for/

So I didn't allocate memory for my acceleration buffer, this here:

```
- == bottom acceleration structure ==
- get acceleration structure build sizes info
- create buffer (acceleration structure storage, shader device address) <---- no memory
```

Before I noticed the post on reddit I already allocated memory for my scratch buffer, because I thought that it is needed, because I get the device address from it. But somewhere in Web I read about the acceleration structure buffer, that it doesn't need any memory allocation and that this is done behind the scenes. But this is not the case :)

So now my code is working and I can continue to learn and build the top level acceleration structure now :)

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the meantime:

- rebuild entire initialization code of vulkan (now I use .hpp instead of .h, which leads to some nice type checks at compile time)
- everything, every line is typed again by hand (no copy paste), the problem remains
- I have commented out the rasterizer rendering -> no problem (but the problem occurs in acquireNextImage and present, so I need the rasterizer to get the problem)
- if I comment out the building of acceleration structure -> no problem
- if I put a breakpoint after (!) building the acc structure., but in synchronized area (rasterizer can't run at this point and must wait at CPU side) -> no problem

My conclusion: I miss some synchronization between building the Acc Structure and the rasterization. I don't know where I miss it, because I use different:

- queue families (rasterizer uses graphics queue family 0, acc structure compute queue family 1)
- different semaphores (acc builder and rasterizer has their own semaphores and fences)
- I do not use the acc buffer yet, I only create it.

I don't know, what is going on there. Why all is fine, if I pause with breakpoint? Because, if a parameter would be wrong, I should get the same problems with a breakpoint, should I? So my understanding is, that there is something wrong with synchronization. But problem is also, that acquireNextImage fails with a DeviceLost error. And this might be a wrong parameter, out of range pointer, etc.

I'm going to investigate deeper... ^^